# 'init is not a function' while React Codesplitting

Tags: reactjs

I have 'init is not a function error when I try to do codesplit. I have a folder named 'Pages' which has index.js from where 'Home is exported'. Pages folder also has another folder named 'PrivcacyPolicies' which contains a file 'PrivacyPolicy.js' from which 'PrivacyPolicy' is imported.

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const Privacy = lazy(() => import('./pages/PrivacyPolicies/PrivacyPolicy.js'));
const Home = lazy(() => import('./pages'));

const App = () => (
<Router>
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy}/>
</Switch>
</Suspense>
</Router>
 );


export default App;
```